Car overheated and shut of while driving, now the car won't start, it cranks but won't start, makes sound like its running out of gas. Yes it has gas
2007 Nissan Murano SL AWD V6
Bought new battery, replaced battery fuse changed spark plugs and coils.
Checked fuel pump - it works, battery drains, now I just found water coming out of the exhaust pipe under car.
Changed air filter, fuel gauge movies between half a tank and a quarter of a tank which I know it has a quarter of a tank in it.
Checked all hoses - no cracks or holes.

I don't know enough to make this an actual answer, but... overheating and then water coming out of the exhaust pipe sounds possibly like the nightmare that is a broken head gasket. Which would mean your coolant water entering the cylinder, which... is VERY bad. I hope it's something else.

When you removed spark plugs, were all or some wet from coolant? A blown head gasket will suck coolant and drown spark, and push fuel/oil into coolant, turning coolant into chocolate. Did plugs smell of fuel? Can you perform a spark test? Can you spray starting fluid into the intake and see if the engine will start?

When a car overheats, neither the battery nor the spark plugs are first to suffer.
The most probable result is the cylinder head bending out of proper shape, but your case may vary.
Things to check first:

The level and the condition of the engine oil. No oil or oil with milky color = engine head repair.
The level and the condition of the coolant. No coolant = try to top it first, oily droplets = head repair. Leaks? Fix them first.
Error codes. See how these are read in your car and what they mean.
The exact meaning of "overheat" - steam from the radiator? red light on the dashboard? How did you know the car overheated?
How did the old spark plugs looked like?
Are all belts in good condition and tension?


First thing I'd do is a compression test and exhaust test.
A lot of the big box (auto zone, advance) stores will let you borrow them (or pay and return when you're done)
I'll bet it's a bad head gasket, but I'd search youtube for how to use these two tools and go borrow some to test your engine.
I have a feeling you either warped the head or blew the head gasket. If you didn't, that's good but you need to check that since overheating can cause that.
